# Can someone help me, I cannot access/use my portable hard-drive, Samsung S2 Portable 600gb

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, external-hard-drive

Its okay for me to reformat it, theres no important files there, but I just cannot go through with it, it says there: There is no Disk in the drive, insert a disk then try again, etc., etc.

Also - Disk Management says:

Disk 3
Unknown
596.17 GB
Unreadable

596.17 GB
Unallocated

How to fix this. If I could recover the files, better, if not, atleast I want to have it reformatted so I can still use it.

Note: This was used in MacBook laptop before, is there any related connections or just the same as with Windows-based PC?

How can I have this fixed, reformatted again?

Comment: did you format the drive when you used it with your MacBook?

Comment: my guess is that it was Formatted HFS+, and as such windows Doesn't Recognize it.  There are drivers (paragon) which supposedly allow you to read HFS+ on windows, but have never tried them.  to just reuse the drive you should be able to delete the partition in Disk Manager and create a new one (if you make it VFAT you can read it on both Windows/OS X)

Answer (score 0):

The Mac FAT system may be why it is unreadable. If you want to have both Mac and Windows read a hard drive, you need to initialize the disc in computer management and format using FAT32 in Windows. Then Mac and Windows should be able to read and write to it afterwards.

Comment: There is no such thing as a Mac FAT file system. You are probably thinking HFS+